# Vuejs3 component unknown error when inject using createApp function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, vuejs3, inertiajs

I build an diagram using D3.js and use JavaScript to inject component with props.

```js
const app = createApp(StoryStep, {core: this.$page.props.core, step: d.data})
    .mount(document.createElement('div'))
return app.$el.outerHTML
```

But after inject the child component give me error show below.

```
Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')
    at FormMetadata._collectTextSample (chrome-extension://pejdijmoenmkgeppbflobdenhhabjlaj/content_script.js:1:188809)
    at FormMetadata._collectFormMetadata (chrome-extension://pejdijmoenmkgeppbflobdenhhabjlaj/content_script.js:1:209345)
    at FormMetadata._collectMetadata (chrome-extension://pejdijmoenmkgeppbflobdenhhabjlaj/content_script.js:1:214410)
    at FormMetadata.formsAndMetadata (chrome-extension://pejdijmoenmkgeppbflobdenhhabjlaj/content_script.js:1:217067)
    at RunHeuristics (chrome-extension://pejdijmoenmkgeppbflobdenhhabjlaj/content_script.js:1:229254)
    at chrome-extension://pejdijmoenmkgeppbflobdenhhabjlaj/content_script.js:1:233683
```

**[EDIT 1]**

I comment out all the `input` and `select`, the error will gone. But, when added back, error come out again.

```
<input type="text" value="hello">
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: There's not enough context to reproduce the problem. Can you share a link to a reproduction?

Comment: Do you ever append the element to the DOM?